# How to find model in yii2 by date, only year

Tags: php, sql, date, activerecord, yii2

I need find a model but only compare years in a date field.

```
$fecha_actual = date("d-m-Y");
//resto 1 año
$old_year=date("d-m-Y",strtotime($fecha_actual."- 1 year"));
$diff=Differentiation::findOne(['date' => $old_year,'id_status'=>4]);
```

I tried this but not work

```
 $old_year=date("Y",strtotime($fecha_actual."- 1 year"));
 $diff=Differentiation::findOne(['YEAR(date)' => $old_year,'id_status'=>4]);
```

some help please.

Comment: if I use this it work but i dont wanna use this way `Differentiation::findBySql('select * from differentiation where extract(year from date)='.$old_year.' and id_status=4');`

Comment: There is an space between minus and 1 , please remove it and try again.

Answer (score 0):

hear is solution for previous year record list

```
$diff=Differentiation::findOne(['DATE_FORMAT(date,"%Y")' => (date("Y") - 1),'id_status'=>4]);
```

Comment: get this error 'Key "DATE_FORMAT(date,"%Y")" is not a column name and can not be used as a filter'. Wy?

Comment: the name of column date it is 'date'